# Unable to Load Resource Using getResource

Tags: groovy

I am trying to simply load a file from a packages resource folder. I have the following project structure:

[image]

And have tried the following in an attempt to load each of the txt files to the Populator.groovy script:

```
File file = new File(Populator.class.getResource("/names/first-names.txt").getFile())
```

The above results in a FileNotFoundException if any methods are called from the file instance. The path returned is correct, and the file is indeed where the path specifies. I am also using very similar methods of extracting resources in above modules and no errors are occurring. Whats going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```
File file = new File(Populator.class.getResource("/names/first-names.txt").toURI())
```

Not sure why you want it as a file though? Wouldn't an input stream do?

Comment: Thanks, It worked. And I originally had it setup as an inputstream but I started using getFile just because that's what I saw in a majority of other examples and it seemed to do the trick for them. Thanks again.

Comment: Inputstream is invariably easier